# Magento 2.4.4: Paypal Payments Pro test mode not working

Tags: magento2, checkout, paypal, paypal-payments-pro

I hve enabled test mode from the Magento admin as well as from the paypal dashboard, however, when I try to place an order using a test card it gives me this error:

```
Some required information is missing or incorrect. Please correct the fields below and try again.

  Error: PayPal Express Checkout is not setup on this account.
```

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when Paypal Express Checkout is not set up on that particular Payflow merchant ID you are using (for the particular mode you are doing transactions in, be it TEST or LIVE)

Furthermore, to reproduce the issue:

- Try clearing your cookies and your cache (bin/magento cache:clean && bin/magento cache:flush)
- Check the error logs
- Check your Paypal account setting
- Check server error logs
- Check the Paypal request and response data it receives while making payment.
- Check the API username and password to set up the sandbox request.

Please check the link to check further for the issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/31105